# Why we use A Constant int RC_SIGN_IN = 007

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Customizing G+ button
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfilePic);

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOut();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Please give me in detail answer about why we use The constant in this
Why we use `A Constant int RC_SIGN_IN = 007 
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007`

Comment: your question is unclear, explain it please

Comment: Looks like you use it to check the activity result. You startActivityForResult passing this constant and so the onResult will get this value back as long as it comes from the activity you started.

Comment: thanks i have understood

Comment: what is the use of .build() method here

Answer (score 2):

There could be many activities which you can start to get some sort of result from an activity and you receive those results in only one method of the activity i.e  **onActivityResult()**. 
In order to differentiate which type of result you have received you make use of Request codes, which is in-fact just a unique constant integer.

So When the Google sign in process returns the sign-in result (success or failure) it returns using the request code so that you can check the result which you just received is a Sig-in result and get the data in the required data type.

Comment: what is the use of .build() method and what is actually trying to bulid

Comment: build() is used to create a new instance of the GoogleSignIn class have a look at this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html